# How to override the UserAdmin form from SonataUserBundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

Here is the thing.
I started a SonataProject with SonataAdminBundle (v4.22) and SonataUserBundle (v5.4) to manage user.
I would like to override the `configureFormFields` from the `UserAdmin` class.
I need to add a new bool field, but it isn't displayed.
I did not use FosUserBundle.

To do that, I have started to create my own AdminClass `UserAdmin`, which it extends `UserAdmin` class from SonataUserBundle.
I tried to configure field with `configureFormFields`.

Here is my function :

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

class UserAdmin extends \Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Model\UserAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form): void
    {
        parent::configureFormFields($form);
        $form
            ->with('general', ['class' => 'col-md-4'])
                ->add('notification')
            ->end();
    }
}
```

How to make this override applied ?

Thanks.